# How do you find a specific site's Twitter bot?

Tags: support, twitter

How can I find the Twitter bot for a specific SE site? Googling "sitename stackexchange twitter" did not yield results for the site I was looking for. Is there a link to it somewhere on each site, or a listing of them somewhere, or can you find them all once you've found one... etc. Or is there a specific naming convention for them, and I can search for the specific username?

Comment: What you mean "twitter bot" exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to [stackexchange.com, all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and select the list view. You can then easily see twitter links on the sites that have a twitter bot:

> [image: Super User 222k questions twitter blog]

Comment: @Wend please don't remove screenshots that are part of posts. (unless they're offensive of course)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it must have loaded wrongly on my computer; sorry about that. I wasn't trying to remove a screenshot, I thought there was a display error. When I viewed the answer it showed a blank section of the yellow-background `>` stuff; I thought it was a spoiler tag for some reason. But then when I moused over it nothing happened. So when I went to edit I saw a link, assumed the ! had made for the weirdness, and deleted it. I didn't realize there was supposed to be a screenshot!

Comment: @Wendi Oh, I see. The `>` is for quote formatting, added to screenshots that contain text to prevent people from thinking it's part of the post itself. The image probably was slow to load on your end. :-)